# OAuth gem get_request_token Net::HTTPFatalError

Tags: ruby, api, oauth, rubygems

I use oauth gem - https://rubygems.org/gems/oauth to do a oauth operation.

I followed the document: http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/oauth/ and Oauth ruby examples: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OAuth_ruby_examples

Such as:

```
@consumer=OAuth::Consumer.new ENV["consumer_key"], 
                          ENV["consumer_secret"], 
                          {:site=>ENV["api_url"]}

@request_token = @consumer.get_request_token
```

Here I can see the `@consumer` values. But it went error when run this: `@consumer.get_request_token`:

```
Net::HTTPFatalError (500 "Internal Server Error"):
```

When I see the source code of oauth gem:

> https://github.com/oauth-xx/oauth-ruby/blob/master/lib/oauth/consumer.rb#L124

If I don't set `oauth_callback`, it will be `OAuth::OUT_OF_BAND`.

Is it the reason of above? Should I must set a `callback`?